# Tapping Status Bar in MobileSafari does not work on my test page

Tags: javascript, ios, html, safari, mobile-safari

I am trying to debug this and can't make any headway. I've got this HTML5 JavaScript library I am building and the test page for it can contain large volumes of output as I am piping `console.log` and exceptions out into the DOM to quickly inspect them on mobile devices (it is the only way I know of inspecting state on an Android device for instance)

[Here](http://unphased.github.com/ply/test.html) is the page. So long as I don't push up broken code while I work on this you should be able to produce plenty of debug output which will be pumped into the `<body>` thus allowing the page to scroll. Note also to toggle the visibility of the big blue debug panel you can tap the header text at the top of the page (like a button).

The issue is specific to iOS: Tapping the iOS status bar does not work in either portrait or landscape modes, and I am not sure what it is I have done with JS or otherwise that has disabled this quite handy feature.

Comment: I'm not seeing a status bar... are you talking about the header text on the page, or the actual iOS built in status bar?

Comment: iOS built-in status bar: It should scroll up the current view whenever you tap it (this is the functionality I'm trying to get back). If you notice it working for you please report that also

Comment: That works fine for me, but that's a built in property of the OS. What makes you think you can change that functionality with javascript?

Comment: @roviuser Yes, Exactly!!! I expected never to be able to affect that behavior, for the exact reason you said. When I discovered my devices respond fine to it in other websites but not in this particular test page of mine I was, and still am, confused.

Comment: It looks like I can scroll the main view and the sidebar separately by tapping the status bar above each.

Comment: What is your device and version @roviuser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use of `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch` appears to be the culprit for iOS6 here. It actually looks like iOS5 is less broken w.r.t. this issue.

I think there may be a way to work around the issue by dynamically setting `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch` on the elements that need it by catching touch events on them. Or just leave it off as they still remain usable (just have no momentum).